# Array function of JavaScript && Rest Parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was reading the JavaScript Docs I found the Array function section one Example that I could not understand properly. Because I am learning Programming.

```
function multiply(multiplier, ...theArgs){
    return theArgs.map(x=> multiplier*x);
}

var arr = multiply(2,1,2,3);
console.log(arr);
```

Above example is giving

> 2,4,6

My first question why is used 3 dots(...) before function argument name (...theArgs) for? And How did it calculate 2,4,6? 
And the second Question is about rest parameter. What does the rest parameter use in Array Function?

I would be glad if anyone can give me some real-life object example to understand this Problem

Comment: `...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: It allows multiple arguments.  As George said its called the spread operator.  Examples of use can be found at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Actually @George it is referred to as rest spread syntax https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/ it does more than just spread, depending on context of use

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak no, that's what it's called in babel, which is a compiler for javascript.

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread @George and the proposal is named that because? I'm not trying to be rude, just informing you that it is not merely the spread operator